# What are some problems that could cause Magento to redirect to /downloader/ (Installation wizard)

Tags: magento

I have a site that has been running fine for awhile.  Ran an SVN update after making some changes in the development environment.  Now the site keeps redirecting to the Installation Wizard (/downloader/) No matter what I do.  Checked and double checked database settings - all seems good.  Can anyone tell me what other problems could have this result?  I just wish it would give me a freaking error so I could more easily troubleshoot the actual problem.

Comment: Is your app/etc/local.xml file in place and readable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you check the index.php file you will see the following...

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}
```

That is to say, if there is no app/Mage.php file and there is a downloader folder, it will redirect to it.

Comment: I've seen a similar issue (redirects to the installer) if app/etc/local.xml does not exist or is not readable by the web server.

Comment: In my case file exists, but `file_exists($mageFilename)` still returns `false`. If I echo `$mageFilename` and `cat` it on server it finds the file, but PHP says file is not there. Files have full permissions (777). What is going on??

Comment: I have the same problem... Everything exist's but the Install wizzard is called... How did you solve it??

Comment: If the file definitely exists, the most likely problem is the file permissions as mentioned by @KoviNET .

Comment: I had this error and as per the logic above my Mage.php was missing so it was redirecting to /downloader/ - I jusst copied Mage.php back into /app/ and problem solved - a mystery for us though how Mage.php vanished?!

Answer (score 4):

Check is your app/etc/local.xml file found and readable (644) by the webserver, this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted both the /var/cache and /var/session directories. It appears to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

wrong permissions may cause that. had this problem when updated magento core while under root, chown to www-data fixed the problem